# Pandas: how to collapse a categorical column returning aggregate values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do something slightly counter-intuitive. The issue, which should be clear in the reproducible example below, is that I'm trying to collapse a column of categorical values whilst returning aggregate values for the other columns.

```
raw_data = {
        'id': ['4', '5', '6', '7'],
        'score1': ['1', '2', '4', '0'], 
        'score2': ['3', '4', '11', '0'], 
        'time1': ['7.3', '2.4', '0.0', '0.3'], 
        'time2': ['4.3', '5.4', '1.0', '0.0']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['id', 'score1', 'score2', 'time1', 'time2'])
df 

    id  score1  score2   time1  time2
0   4       1       3    7.3    4.3
1   5       2       4    2.4    5.4
2   6       4       11   0.0    1.0
3   7       0       0    0.3    0.0
```

From this dataframe I'm trying to return a one line pandas HTML table showing:

1. The sum of `score1`
2. The sum of `score2`
3. The mean of `time1`
4. The median of `time2`

Ideally the `id` column would show something like `all`. This value can of course easily be changed after the event.

The one line HTML table would look like this:

```
id    score1  score2   time1  time2
All   7       18       2.5    2.7
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by HTML table? do you want python to return the table in HTML code?

Comment: As in: when working in an IPython notebook you can print a properly formatted pandas HTML table. For example when you call df.head().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do something like:

```
df = df.astype('float64')
tmp = pd.DataFrame([{"score1": df.score1.sum(), "score2":df.score2.sum(), "time1":df.time1.mean(), "time2":df.time2.median()}])
out = tmp.to_html(index=False)
```

which gives the table like so

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">  <thead>    <tr style="text-align: right;">     <th>score1</th>     <th>score2</th>      <th>time1</th>     <th>time2</th>   </tr> </thead>  <tbody>   <tr>      <td>7</td>     <td>18</td>      <td>2.5</td>      <td>2.65</td>    </tr>  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Really elegant. Had no idea you could create a dataframe like this.